# How to set subset_ratio and minimal gain parameters in R?

Tags: r, random-forest

How can I set the "subset_ratio" and "minimal_gain" parameters of a Random Forest in R?

Looking at the documentation of Random Forest at `?randomForest`, I cannot see any particular parameter for this purpose.